# Fedora Virtualbox VM details UI when clicked not visible?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am in Fedora and I have installed  virtualbox latest, earlier it was showing the UI of a VM when I click on it but later on , I initiated File manager and now I can only see below components on the right side

1. Extensions
2. Media
3. Network
4. Cloud
5. Activities

When I click on any machine it is not showing any details, The UI shows me the active UI components from above. I checked everything in "User interface" inside settings but still no solution. I searched google but never found such issue by anyone. How do i bring the machine details back ?

[image]

Comment: Your VMs seem to be switched off.

Comment: VMs are switched off, yes but it shows me details right when i click on any machine ? on the right side ?
for e.g:
https://imgs.search.brave.com/YbYZd7nKp2e2uieHvWqmZ7k5J2LYDJd050tGjfcxZ_4/rs:fit:860:0:0/g:ce/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cu/dmlydHVhbGJveC5v/cmcvbWFudWFsL2lt/YWdlcy9jbG91ZHZt/LW92ZXJ2aWV3LnBu/Zw

Comment: You seem to be in Activity Overview. DDid you try clicking on settings?

Comment: I clicked on settings, it gives me a new window of settings for that VM which has "general", "system" ... etc. I actually have a snapshot of a VM that I want to delete and that's only visible in the "Details" UI of a vm. but either way I wanted that details UI pane back

Comment: Maybe redo the update is best then. If something ain't broken, don't fix it ;-)

Comment: if i uninstall and reinstall virtualbox, will that fix it ?

Comment: Never been in that situation, so I don't know. Answer is: maybe

Comment: Didn't go away. Sadly. I wanted to view general settings on the right side